# Activate AzureDevops Server warehouse only

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to restore the reports data in Azure Devops Server.
I am wondering how to restore only the database TFS_Warehouse as named in the documentation.

I have created an empty database called something like TFS_Warehouse as mentioned in the documentation. Testing the connection on that part is okay.

I am trying to activate only the warehouse and not the Analysis services or reports.

The reports wizard in Azure Devops administration console does not seem to allow only this and requires that all fields are filled.

How can I use only the warehouse ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Pierre P. Any update on this case, have you checked Shamrai Aleksander's reply which should be helpful. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi, I have checked it, but the link leads to the documentation on processing the warehouse and cube which does not apply to my case.
What I wanted was to be able to have the warehouse activated in Azure Devops Server but not the SSAS with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation here: [Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=dim-work-item)

Try the **ProcessWarehouse** command.